# Referencing powershell functions from script modules

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Is there a shorthand I can write in PowerShell whereby I can only reference my own functions from modules that I have loaded?

For Example:
I have module that I have loaded by doing

```
Import-Module Worktasks
```

Now as the module gets bigger I will start to forget about some of the earlier functions that I wrote. I can, of course, do something like this:

```
(Get-Module -Name worktasks | % ExportedCommands).Values.Name
```

But this will only list the functions that I have wrote but not their parameters. So it would be nice if I could narrow down the results pulled by Intellisense if I could directly reference functions/cmdlets from individual modules in my code.

I am using PowerShell 4.0 in my environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the functions from a specific module, e.g. `worktasks`, like this:

```
(Get-Module -Name worktasks).ExportedCommands.Values
```

By default you'll get a limited amount of information but there is more. If you select everything, then you'll see more information including the parameter sets:

```
(Get-Module -Name worktasks).ExportedCommands.Values | select *
```

If you just want the names and the parameter sets, then this will do just that:

```
(Get-Module -Name worktasks).ExportedCommands.Values | select Name, ParameterSets
```

Comment: Hi Don. Thanks for that. That takes me part of the through and will use that. But what if I wanted to reference a function within worktasks while righting a new script? For example there could be two modules with identical function names and I want to use a function from module1 and not 2. Is there a shorthand way of doing this within PowerShell?

Comment: You will only get the functions from the module you specify (`worktasks` in the example you gave.) You would get all functions from all imported modules if you took out the `-Name worktasks` in the above examples.